# Problema de ligar um Observable

Tags: angular

Antes de mais, desculpem o meu português, não o escrevo bem e estou a usar um tradutor, mas consigo lê-lo suficientemente bem.

Tenho um problema em ligar um observable que crio num serviço com uma variável de um componente.
Aqui está o código:

servicio1.ts

```
         private myObservable$ = new Subject<myInterface>();
            constructor() { 
              this.crearObservable$();
            }

         nuevoObjeto(dato1: string, dato2: string): myInterface {
              return {
              datoUno: dato1,
              datoDos: dato2,
             };
         }
    
         crearObservable$() {
              let observableAUX: myInterface;
              observableAUX = this.nuevoUsuario("Dato 1", "Dato 2");
              this.myObservable$.next(observableAUX);
         }

         getObservable$(): Observable<myInterface> {
              return this.myObservable$.asObservable();
         }
```

componente1.ts

```
         datos: Observable<myInterface>;
         datos: Usuario;

         ngOnInit(): void {
            this.datos$ = this.servicio1.getObservable$();
            this.datos$.subscribe(datos => this.datos = datos);
            console.log(this.datos);
         }
```

É claro que tanto o serviço como a interface não são importados para lado nenhum.

Mas por alguma razão `estos.dados' não recebem os valores.

Agradecia a vossa ajuda.

Obrigado de antemão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era que eu tinha de me inscrever antes de transmitir, por isso só tive de chamar createObservable$() depois de me ter inscrito:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.datos$ = this.servicio1.getObservable$();
    this.datos$.subscribe(datos => this.datos = datos);
    console.log(this.datos);
    this.servicio1.crearObservable$();
}
```